# How to set background image "under" all miglayout's cells

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, miglayout

Here is my background without using miglayout

```
private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("pic1.jpg"));
        frame.add(background); 
}
```

It looks very nice
[image]

---

But I want to use MigLayout

Here is the code

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(800, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[800px]", "[500px]"));

    JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("pic1.jpg"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(background, "cell 0 0,grow"); 
            // also tried the following to force background "under" all cells 
            // frame.getContentPane().add(background); 
 }
```

It looks very bad 
Where do those top and right white boarders come from ? Why does not the image fully display ?
[image]

Comment: Your manually setting your GUI's size is usually a bad idea. Rather let the components size themselves and the GUI in a more "natural" way. Also, most components added on to the background using container should probably not be opaque.

Comment: Thank you . . i tried correcting size and removing opaque . Still can't get the exact same result . Is there any way to set a background image that would be "under" all mig cells ?

Comment: I tried to set (700, 400) still have boarders and the image is not fully displayed

Comment: Use `MigLayout("insets 0");` to remove the empty spaces and `frame.pack();` instead of fixed sizes.

Answer (score 5):

- `frame.setSize(800, 500);` is including `Borders`, then absolute coordinated `new MigLayout("", "[800px]", "[500px]")` used as constant in `MigLayout` are greater than `JFrame` without/minus `Borders`, part of your image is painted off screen,
- you can to simulating by using `frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug", "[400px]", "[300px]"));` instread of `frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[400px]", "[300px]"));`
- use `JFrame.pack()` before `JFrame.setVisible(true)`
- used most of details from your code

[image]

EDIT

by removing default gap

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigAndIcon {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private Random random = new Random();
    private Timer backTtimer;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    public MigAndIcon() {
        //frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[400px]", "[300px]"));
        frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0, debug", "[400px]", "[300px]"));
        frame.add(label, "cell 0 0, grow"); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        startBackground();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void startBackground() {
        backTtimer = new javax.swing.Timer(1500, updateBackground());
        backTtimer.start();
        backTtimer.setRepeats(true);
    }

    private Action updateBackground() {
        return new AbstractAction("Background action") {
            private final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getImage()));
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigAndIcon t = new MigAndIcon();
            }
        });
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        int w = label.getWidth();
        int h = label.getHeight();
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, new Color(
                127 + random.nextInt(128),
                127 + random.nextInt(128),
                127 + random.nextInt(128)),
                w, w,
                new Color(random.nextInt(128), random.nextInt(128), random.nextInt(128)));
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
        g2d.setPaint(gp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        return bi;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add `insets 0` to make me happy and your answer will be perfect :).

Comment: @Anthony Accioly but I think that default gap is acceptable, in Standard Layout Managers you have to creating ..............

Comment: Oh come on... Let's kill insets and breed bugs :). Yes, you did it!